# User interaction blocking new annotations views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I developed a small application using `MKMapView` where `MKAnnotations` are added continuously on the map. It works well as long as the user does not touch the map view.

If the user tries to interact with the map, I noticed that no new `MKAnnotationViews` are added to the map. In fact, I discovered that as long as the user keeps interacting with the map, `mapView: didAddAnnotationViews:` is not called. As soon as the user's finger leaves the screen, `mapView: didAddAnnotationViews:` is called, passing in argument all the `MKAnnotationViews` that should have been added.

I tried forcing a call to `mapView: didAddAnnotationViews`, but I need to pass the `MKAnnotationViews` as arguments (so I can't used anything based on periodic calls), and when I try to call it at the end of `mapView: viewForAnnotation:`, it doesn't work since the view as not yet been added to the mapView. It is also a bad idea to try and add the annotation via another thread, since this will result in a `Collection was mutated while being enumerated` exception (probably coming from the mutable array storing the annotation views).

Is there any way to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class which implement  delegate.

Than you can use MKAnnotationView's `initWithAnnotation:` method to create your annotations and add them in an array.

Then you can add them all to the map by using `addAnnotations:` method to add your annotations.

As long as you use custom annotations you need to manually create them, so user can't.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really answer my question. I cannot store all the annotations in an array since they come from a stream.